# If $n$ is composite then there are integers $a$ and $b$ such that $n$ divides $ab$ but $n$ divides neither $a$ nor $b$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Theorem says-

> If $n$ is composite then there are integers $a$ and $b$ such that $n$ divides $ab$ but $n$ divides neither $a$ nor $b$.

I knew that proof could be simple enough if we suppose n=$ab $ . But I want to know about any other better method of proving it.
Sorry for latex mistakes.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Just look at a particular case.  $2\cdot 3=6$, but $6$ doesn't divide either $2$ or $3$.  What about if $3\cdot 4=12$, but $6$ doesn't divide $3$ or $4$..  try and formalize from there...

Comment: *NB:* There's a difference between "sorry for" and "sorry about". Also, for a MathJax (*i.e.*, $\LaTeX$) tutorial, see [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041).

Comment: Thanks shaun & eleven_eleven ok I am trying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proof 1**

Since $n$ is composite, just assume $n=a·b$. Thus

> $$n\mid a·b\quad n\nmid a\quad n\nmid b$$

---

**Proof 2**

In virtue of the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic) $$n=\prod ^k_{i=0}p_i^{\alpha_i}$$ where there are at least two primes $p_1$ and $p_2$ which divide $n$ (since $n$ is composite). So we can divide it into two parts: $$n=\prod ^{k-j}_{i=0}p_i^{\alpha_i}\times \prod ^k_{h=k-j+1}p_h^{\alpha_h}$$

Take now a prime $t>n$ (which you can certainly find since there are [infinitely many primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem)).

Note that

> $$n\mid \prod ^{k-j}_{i=0}p_i^{\alpha_i}\times \prod ^k_{h=k-j+1}p_h^{\alpha_h}\times t$$

However

> $$n \nmid \prod ^{k-j}_{i=0}p_i^{\alpha_i}\quad \text{and} \quad n\nmid \prod ^k_{h=k-j+1}p_h^{\alpha_h}\times t$$

Comment: Thankuh Sir. Please read the description again.

Comment: This one is longer, but I hope it helps

Comment: Is it now better @BORNTOLEARN??

Comment: Yes sir.It seems better.

Comment: @BORNTOLEARN You can also upvote or accept the answer if you liked it ;)

Comment: Yes for sure Dr. Mathva's